# Sum of consecutive, positive Integers

Tags: c#, linq

I want to sum up consecutive positive integers (starting a new sum at each negative value)

***Input:***

```
int[] input = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, -1, 1, 3, -2, 3, 4 };
```

***Output:***

```
output = { 6,4,7 }; // 1+2+3=6, 1+3=4, 3+4=7
```

i tried something like `input.Where(x => x > 0).Sum();` but that does not work

Comment: @Sayse - OP said consecutive positive integers,1 & 3 are consecutive after -1 :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to add, here is a solution using LINQ without the need for an extra extension method:

```
int[] list = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, -1, 1, -2, 3, 4 };
int count = 0;

var result = list
    .GroupBy(n => n < 0 ? ++count : count)
    .Select(x => x.Sum(n => n > 0 ? n : 0));
```

Comment: Really? Sum all positive integers that occur in groups of (specifically) 3? This is not what the OP asked for. This is brittle in the extreme. Supposing the input list changes to `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, -1, 1, -2, 3, 4 }`?

Comment: @spender, not sure how it's brittle.  In your example, it would result in `{ 6, 5, 7}`

Comment: A reminder of OPs question: "I want to sum up consecutive positive integers (starting a new sum at each negative value)". So from the test case I gave above, wouldn't we expect `{10, 1, 7}`?

Comment: @spender, Ah, I missed that it starts a new group at each negative integer.

Comment: @spender, Updated to correct my misunderstanding of the requirements.

Answer (score 9):

Using the [`ChunkBy` extension provided by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc138361.aspx) (which is used for finding *contiguous* items in a sequence), you can do this in a single line:

```
var outSeq = input
  .ChunkBy(x => x >= 0 ? 1 : -1)
  .Where(g => g.Key > 0)
  .Select(g => g.Sum());
```

Here is the `ChunkBy` code, reproduced here to guard against potential link-rot (note, this is Microsoft's work, not my own... see link above for original source and some background information):

```
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> ChunkBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector)
    {
        return source.ChunkBy(keySelector, EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default);
    }

    public static IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TSource>> ChunkBy<TSource, TKey>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
    {
        // Flag to signal end of source sequence. 
        const bool noMoreSourceElements = true;

        // Auto-generated iterator for the source array.        
        var enumerator = source.GetEnumerator();

        // Move to the first element in the source sequence. 
        if (!enumerator.MoveNext()) yield break;

        // Iterate through source sequence and create a copy of each Chunk. 
        // On each pass, the iterator advances to the first element of the next "Chunk" 
        // in the source sequence. This loop corresponds to the outer foreach loop that 
        // executes the query.
        Chunk<TKey, TSource> current = null;
        while (true)
        {
            // Get the key for the current Chunk. The source iterator will churn through 
            // the source sequence until it finds an element with a key that doesn't match. 
            var key = keySelector(enumerator.Current);

            // Make a new Chunk (group) object that initially has one GroupItem, which is a copy of the current source element.
            current = new Chunk<TKey, TSource>(key, enumerator, value => comparer.Equals(key, keySelector(value)));

            // Return the Chunk. A Chunk is an IGrouping<TKey,TSource>, which is the return value of the ChunkBy method. 
            // At this point the Chunk only has the first element in its source sequence. The remaining elements will be 
            // returned only when the client code foreach's over this chunk. See Chunk.GetEnumerator for more info. 
            yield return current;

            // Check to see whether (a) the chunk has made a copy of all its source elements or  
            // (b) the iterator has reached the end of the source sequence. If the caller uses an inner 
            // foreach loop to iterate the chunk items, and that loop ran to completion, 
            // then the Chunk.GetEnumerator method will already have made 
            // copies of all chunk items before we get here. If the Chunk.GetEnumerator loop did not 
            // enumerate all elements in the chunk, we need to do it here to avoid corrupting the iterator 
            // for clients that may be calling us on a separate thread. 
            if (current.CopyAllChunkElements() == noMoreSourceElements)
            {
                yield break;
            }
        }
    }

    // A Chunk is a contiguous group of one or more source elements that have the same key. A Chunk  
    // has a key and a list of ChunkItem objects, which are copies of the elements in the source sequence. 
    class Chunk<TKey, TSource> : IGrouping<TKey, TSource>
    {
        // INVARIANT: DoneCopyingChunk == true ||  
        //   (predicate != null && predicate(enumerator.Current) && current.Value == enumerator.Current) 

        // A Chunk has a linked list of ChunkItems, which represent the elements in the current chunk. Each ChunkItem 
        // has a reference to the next ChunkItem in the list. 
        class ChunkItem
        {
            public ChunkItem(TSource value)
            {
                Value = value;
            }
            public readonly TSource Value;
            public ChunkItem Next = null;
        }
        // The value that is used to determine matching elements 
        private readonly TKey key;

        // Stores a reference to the enumerator for the source sequence 
        private IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator;

        // A reference to the predicate that is used to compare keys. 
        private Func<TSource, bool> predicate;

        // Stores the contents of the first source element that 
        // belongs with this chunk. 
        private readonly ChunkItem head;

        // End of the list. It is repositioned each time a new 
        // ChunkItem is added. 
        private ChunkItem tail;

        // Flag to indicate the source iterator has reached the end of the source sequence. 
        internal bool isLastSourceElement = false;

        // Private object for thread syncronization 
        private object m_Lock;

        // REQUIRES: enumerator != null && predicate != null 
        public Chunk(TKey key, IEnumerator<TSource> enumerator, Func<TSource, bool> predicate)
        {
            this.key = key;
            this.enumerator = enumerator;
            this.predicate = predicate;

            // A Chunk always contains at least one element.
            head = new ChunkItem(enumerator.Current);

            // The end and beginning are the same until the list contains > 1 elements.
            tail = head;

            m_Lock = new object();
        }

        // Indicates that all chunk elements have been copied to the list of ChunkItems,  
        // and the source enumerator is either at the end, or else on an element with a new key. 
        // the tail of the linked list is set to null in the CopyNextChunkElement method if the 
        // key of the next element does not match the current chunk's key, or there are no more elements in the source. 
        private bool DoneCopyingChunk { get { return tail == null; } }

        // Adds one ChunkItem to the current group 
        // REQUIRES: !DoneCopyingChunk && lock(this) 
        private void CopyNextChunkElement()
        {
            // Try to advance the iterator on the source sequence. 
            // If MoveNext returns false we are at the end, and isLastSourceElement is set to true
            isLastSourceElement = !enumerator.MoveNext();

            // If we are (a) at the end of the source, or (b) at the end of the current chunk 
            // then null out the enumerator and predicate for reuse with the next chunk. 
            if (isLastSourceElement || !predicate(enumerator.Current))
            {
                enumerator = null;
                predicate = null;
            }
            else
            {
                tail.Next = new ChunkItem(enumerator.Current);
            }

            // tail will be null if we are at the end of the chunk elements 
            // This check is made in DoneCopyingChunk.
            tail = tail.Next;
        }

        // Called after the end of the last chunk was reached. It first checks whether 
        // there are more elements in the source sequence. If there are, it  
        // Returns true if enumerator for this chunk was exhausted. 
        internal bool CopyAllChunkElements()
        {
            while (true)
            {
                lock (m_Lock)
                {
                    if (DoneCopyingChunk)
                    {
                        // If isLastSourceElement is false, 
                        // it signals to the outer iterator 
                        // to continue iterating. 
                        return isLastSourceElement;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        CopyNextChunkElement();
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        public TKey Key { get { return key; } }

        // Invoked by the inner foreach loop. This method stays just one step ahead 
        // of the client requests. It adds the next element of the chunk only after 
        // the clients requests the last element in the list so far. 
        public IEnumerator<TSource> GetEnumerator()
        {
            //Specify the initial element to enumerate.
            ChunkItem current = head;

            // There should always be at least one ChunkItem in a Chunk. 
            while (current != null)
            {
                // Yield the current item in the list. 
                yield return current.Value;

                // Copy the next item from the source sequence,  
                // if we are at the end of our local list. 
                lock (m_Lock)
                {
                    if (current == tail)
                    {
                        CopyNextChunkElement();
                    }
                }

                // Move to the next ChunkItem in the list.
                current = current.Next;
            }
        }

        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to loop through yourself. `input.Where(x => x > 0).Sum();` will sum up all positive elements to one sum. you can try this:

```
int[] input = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, -1, 1, 3, -2, 3, 4 };

// a list is easier to use dynamic sizes
List<int> sums = new List<int>();

// the sum to the next negative number
int tmp_sum = 0;

// loop through
foreach(int _element in input)
{
    if(_element <= 0 )
    {
        if(tmp_sum > 0)
        {
            // negative element found, so save the sum if it is bigger than 0 
            sums.Add(tmp_sum);
            tmp_sum = 0;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        // keep summing up
        tmp_sum += _element;
    }    
}

//save the last one, if it is bigger than 0
if(tmp_sum > 0)
    sums.Add(tmp_sum);

// convert to an array
int[] result = sums.ToArray();
```

[**> here**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ncrmYI) you have an executable example.